VSCode server has a mystery Github token
I'm using VSCode Remote to login to a remote Linux host which has a cloned Github repo. The remote is using HTTPS, not SSH.
Somehow, I'm able to authenticate against the repo, with a token that only VSCode's Ask Pass seems to carry.
I have checked:

Fine-grained tokens
Classic tokens
OAuth apps
Github Apps
SSH keys
Passkeys
Regular password (changed it)

I've completely cleared everything above, and verified the user ID it is using is in fact mine. This mystery token still allows both reads and writes to my repo.
I'm disturbed by this - how can I find the origin of a mystery Github token so that I can safely revoke it?
